# Using <ui:include> in center facet of <af:decorativeBox>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets, oracle-adf

I moved from JSF 1.2 using JSP to JSF 2.1 using Facelets.

I use oracle ADF Faces as component library.

The layout of my main page doesn't work anymore with Facelets.

Here is my layout :

```
<af:form id="mainForm">
    <af:decorativeBox theme="medium" styleClass="AFVisualRoot">
    <f:facet name="center">
        <!-- Main page -->
        <af:panelStretchLayout topHeight="35" bottomHeight="20" >                       
        <!-- Top menu -->
        <f:facet name="top">
            <af:panelStretchLayout endWidth="255" startWidth="100%">
            <f:facet name="end">    
            </f:facet> 
            <f:facet name="start">
            </f:facet>
            </af:panelStretchLayout>                            
        </f:facet>
        <!-- Page footer -->
        <f:facet name="bottom">
            <af:region id="footerRegion" showHeader="never"
                   value="#{main.footerModel}" />
        </f:facet>
        <!-- Page body -->
        <f:facet name="center">
            <af:panelSplitter orientation="horizontal"
                      splitterPosition="450">
            <f:facet name="first">
                <af:region id="browserRegion" showHeader="never"
                       value="#{main.browserModel}" />
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="second">
                <af:region id="contentRegion" showHeader="never"
                       value="#{main.contentModel}" />
            </f:facet>
            </af:panelSplitter>
        </f:facet>
        </af:panelStretchLayout>
    </f:facet>
    </af:decorativeBox>
</af:form>
```

As it says in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/adf/tag-reference-faces/tagdoc/af_decorativeBox.html) for the center facet of the decorativeBox "*multiple facet components in facelets are not supported by this facet*"

How to do the layout of the page and still benefit from the decorativeBox if I still want to use Facelets ?

---

UPDATE:
my problems comes from using `<ui:include>` inside facets :

```
<!-- Top menu -->
<f:facet name="top">
  <af:panelStretchLayout endWidth="255" startWidth="100%">
    <f:facet name="end">    
    </f:facet> 
    <f:facet name="start">
      <ui:include src="/components/menu.xhtml" />
    </f:facet>
  </af:panelStretchLayout>                          
</f:facet>
```

Here is part of menu.xhtml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:trh="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/html"
    xmlns:tr="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad"
    xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich"
    xmlns:afh="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/html">

    <af:menuBar id="headerMenuBar">
      <!-- Menu Item -->
    </af:menuBar>
</ui:composition>
```

What is the right way to include a page using Facelet inside ADF components ?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on "my main page doesn't work anymore"?
What exactly are you getting? Blank page, exception, 500 error?

Comment: Tip: Don't use ADF, just don't.

Comment: QueryLars, do you have enough practical experience with ADF to make such assumption? Myself, I wouldn't be able to make such statement for other JSF implementations, even if I used some of them here and there. Sure, ADF has some drawbacks, but it also brings lot of functionality beyond other framework do. The biggest problem is there are no people with a strong experience in at least 2 JSF implementations to really compare them.

Comment: @FlorinMarcus, would you confirm that the code I posted as is should display normally ?  I'm not sure anymore of what could be the problem because I have another page with multiple facet component inside decorativeBox that displays as it should.  I have to investigate further to see what is the problem.  I'll probably complete my question later.

Comment: you should use regions and task flows, instead of "include" tags.

Comment: Yes it works using region tag and have a class that extends RegionModel.  I didn't create task flows though, it seems complicated and works without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested your layout with both facelets and jspx and I get the same result : both are working.

Your problem is elsewhere.

UPDATE after the question was updated:

`<ui:include>` tag should be avoided in ADF, please see [Programming Best Practices - ADF Faces & JavaScript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WeJvOeW4dC0)

Comment: Ok, thank you for the answer, I have not access to youtube now.  I'll watch this video later.